# Кнопка "отслеживать" не работает из очереди проверок?

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

По-моему, кнопка `отслеживать` для вопроса не работает из очереди проверок . Причём проблема не только в отображении (*отслеживать* -> *отслеживается*), но вопрос действительно не добавляется в "отслеживаемые", если проверить профиль.

Все остальные кнопки, которые у меня есть (`поделиться`, `править`, `тревога`), работают, `отслеживать` не из очереди проверок тоже работает.

Вот эта проверка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/506061.